# Takes 1 argument, but 2 were given

Tags: python, pygame

update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How do I fix this error?

```
all_sprites.update(dt)
```

It only has 1 argument, but says I have 2?

Comment: The `self` is an *implicit* argument. Remove the `dt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sprite's `update` method already has `self` as an argument.  If you want to pass additional values to it, you have to add them to the function definition.  For example:

```
    def update(self, dt):
```